# NEST not indexing

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Forgive me if this is redundant or I'm missing something simple, but I'm playing around with ElasticSearch (and NEST in particular) to see if it would be a good add for our b2b ecommerce site's search function.

I grabbed the latest NuGet of NEST and then tried to serialize and add something to an index. Here is a snippet of the approach I was using

```cs
        var localhost = new Uri("http://localhost/9200");
        var setting = new ConnectionSettings(localhost).SetDefaultIndex("cpi_catalog");
        var client = new ElasticClient(setting);
        client.MapFromAttributes<Item>();
        var testitem = new Item()
        {
            Description = "test",
            Id = 9999999,
            Manufacturer_Id = 5,
            Quantity_Per_Unit = 1,
            Quantity_Unit_Id = "EA",
            SKU = "AVE29845",
            Subtitle = "test",
            Title = "test"
        };
        var status = client.Index(testitem);
```

However, it seems that testitem is never indexed at all, when I do a GET for /cpi_catalog/items/9999999 I get the following:

```
{"_index":"cpi_catalog","_type":"items","_id":"9999999","exists":false}
```

What seemingly simple thing am I missing here?

EDIT: When debugging, I get back a `Nest.IndexResponse` with all fields `NULL` besides `status.OK` which is `false`

Comment: `new Uri("http://localhost/9200");` I think that / should be  `:` also check `testItem.Isvalid` to see if the the call succeeded.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid like putting a slash where a colon goes. Thanks Martijn, all fixed

Comment: Of course. Thanks for all the support for NEST!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the uri is has a typo:

```
var localhost = new Uri("http://localhost/9200");
```

should probably be:

```
var localhost = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
```